# Eclipse import dependencies that are declared in a Maven Profile

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

**TL;DR**

I must declare some dependencies in a Maven profile and Eclipse is not able to resolve the packages. Example in the image below.

**Full story**

Hi to everyone :D

Right now I'm working in a very fishy project situation. I'm developing a Spring Web MVC based web application and I'm using Google AppEngine DevServer for local development, even tho I'm seriously thinking about migrating from GAE for more than obvious reasons.

The reason why the project is GAE based is because I'm simply continuing the job someone else started time ago.

Anyways, while developing and increasing the app functionality it came the time where persitence engine became a need. I decided to implement MongoDB and yes, I'm aware that you can't use any other thing rather than Datastore in GAE environment. As persistence layer I'm using MongoRepository. Until now everything is ok.

Problems came when testing time arrived. In order to implement intergration tests I used an in-memory db, [Fake Mongo Fongo](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo) in addition to [NoSQLUnit](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit) for data populating.

The main problem is Fongo requires mongo java driver in order to work and I can't declare it,nor any other JDBC dependency, because GAE DevServer won't work. I don't use java-mongo-driver anyware in my app rather than indirectly via Fongo in integration tests.

The solution is to simply skip all test source compilation and declare them in a separate Maven so everytime I want to deploy on the local server I simply skip all tests. That's not a problem because I'm using Jenkins for CI and SonarQube for coverage (with JaCoCo) so I can simply execute tests there.

Right now I have my pom.xml with all the app dependencies in the general  section so I can `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` and then I have a `<profile>` declared as follows:

```
<profile>
            <id>testing</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.12</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.lordofthejars</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nosqlunit-mongodb</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.7</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>

                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.20</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
                            <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>

            </build>
        </profile>
```

So I can `mvn clean test -Ptesting` whenever Jenkins detects a push.

The problem is I can not write code in Eclipse because it does not resolve the imports since they're declared in a profile. E.g.
[image: Eclipse can't resolve dependencies declared in a Maven profile]

How can I import and work with the packages that I declared in a Maven profile?

Thank you :)

P.S.: I decided to tell the full story so maybe someone else who is or will be going thru the same problem can find it. I didn't find any solution to java-mongo-driver and GAE rather than defining profiles and skipping tests.

Comment: As a workaround, you can try adding the missing dependencies manually to the Eclipse project classpath settings (in addition to what the pom says).

Comment: I was thinkin about that too since it's an IDE problem. What really amazes me is that I'm not able to find a solution googling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the solution.**

Turns out that M2Eclipse is working with active profiles and, by default, they're not active. When you declare a profile, if you want to work with it and, obviously, his declared dependencies in Eclipse you must activate it. In order to do so you must:

1. Right Click on your project > Maven > *Select Maven Profiles...*

[image]
 2. Simply select all the profiles you want to import in your workspace. (Checkbox them)

[image]
 3. Job's done.

[image]